# Pandas Value Counts With Constraint For More Than One Occurance

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, kaggle

Working with the Wine Review Data from Kaggle [here](https://www.kaggle.com/zynicide/wine-reviews/data). I am able to return the number of occurrences by variety using value_counts()

[image]

However, I am trying to find a quick way to limit the results to varieties and their counts where there is more than one occurrence.

Trying `df.loc[df['variety'].value_counts()>1].value_counts()`
and `df['variety'].loc[df['variety'].value_counts()>1].value_counts()` 
both return errors.

The results can be turned into a DataFrame and the constraint added there, but something tells me that there is a way more elegant way to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: try df['variety'].value_counts().loc[lambda x : x>1]

Comment: @WenThat did the trick. Do you have a link to the resource for using lambda in this way? Or I should ask. Can you use a lambda expression with loc as a constraint on the results anytime you are using an aggregate function?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

@wen ansered this in the comments.

```
df['variety'].value_counts().loc[lambda x : x>1]
```

Comment: This answer could benefit from a little bit of explenation.

Comment: I think this provides answer to the question. Author was trying to find quick one-liner to filter out those unique data and see only data with more than 1 variety. This does the trick just nice! Thanks

Comment: How do you group this set and create a value like "others"?